# Unable to apply negative lookahead assertion to nagios plugin output on bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, posix, nagios

The following regex works (tried PCRE/PHP flavor of regex via regex101.com) to match lines not containing the codes 201 and 204 in the given log file -

***Regex***

```
/^(?!.*HTTP\/1.1\"\s*(201|204)).*$/gm
```

***Sample log file***

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:35:08 +0000]  "GET //fam/shared_generate_LDA_compliant.php HTTP/1.1" 200 171 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.002
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:35:34 +0000]  "GET /fam/update_daily_cap_in_memcache_contents.php HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 2.032
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:36:01 +0000]  "GET //fam/audience_pixel_cache_generator.php HTTP/1.1" 200 229001 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.063
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:36:01 +0000]  "GET //fam/shared_generate_banner_campaign_assoc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 302 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.406
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:36:02 +0000]  "GET /fam/update_daily_cap_in_memcache_contents.php HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.888
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:36:32 +0000]  "GET /fam/update_daily_cap_in_memcache_contents.php HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.965
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016:11:37:01 +0000]  "GET //fam/audience_pixel_cache_generator.php HTTP/1.1" 200 229001 "-" "curl/7.40.0" - 0.021
```

I would like to apply the same on this nagios plugin command, but it does not work -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_nginx -p /mnt/log/nginx/access_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`_`(date +'%H')`.log "^(?!.*HTTP\/1.1\"\s*(201|204)).*$"
```

Throws error -

```
bash: !.*HTTP\/1.1\"\s*: event not found
```

The following regex works with the nagios plugin command, which finds out lines containing the codes 200 or 201 -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_nginx -p /mnt/log/nginx/access_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`_`(date +'%H')`.log ".*HTTP/1.1\"\s*(200|201)"
```

**Opening bouny**

How to match lines not containing the codes 201 and 204 without using lookaheads in POSIX flavor of regex?

Comment: Use single quotes around the pattern, not double quotes.

Comment: Like this? ` /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_nginx -p /mnt/log/nginx/access_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`_`(date +'%H')`.log '^(?!.*HTTP\/1.1\"\s*(201|204)).*$'`                                                                                                                                                                                                         Still getting error - `UNKNOWN: logwarn(1) error: invalid regular expression "^(?!.*HTTP\/1.1\"\s*(201|204)).*$": Invalid preceding regular expression`

Comment: logwarn uses POSIX extended regular expressions, not PCRE. POSIX doesn't support lookahead.

Comment: @melpomene ok, could you provide some pointers on how to get it done without using lookaheads then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`logwarn`](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage) documentation mentions support for a negative checking expression.

Please try pre-pending an exclamation mark (`!`) before the pattern string to exclude rather than include these matches:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_nginx /mnt/log/nginx/access_(date +'%Y%m%d')_(date +'%H').log '!.*HTTP/1.1\"\s*(205|201)'
```

**Update - The command above was corrected as per the comments below.**

Comment: You are right. logwarn supports it. I admit I didn't look at the manual and in fact didn't put an effort to find it out. A small correction however - the exclamation mark should be inside the quotes, and the quotes need to be single quotes - `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_nginx /mnt/log/nginx/access_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`_`(date +'%H')`.log '!.*HTTP/1.1\"\s*(205|201)'`

Comment: Also, removed the `-p` because it stands for `non-matching` and seems to negate the effect of `!`.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't able to test it out so the answer was only giving the suspected gist of what would be needed. Have now corrected as per your comments above (in case anyone else comes across it and doesn't read the comments).

Comment: please see if you can help with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740449/unable-to-correctly-parse-out-log-lines-containing-particular-keyword-using-ngin

Comment: Please see if you can answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906177/unable-to-capture-changes-to-log-file-via-nagios-command-invoked-via-php-exec