# Unable to correctly parse out log lines containing particular keyword using nginx logwarn

Tags: regex, linux, posix, nagios

With the following log line added after the last invocation of check_logwarn command -

```
[Tue Nov 22 11:04:03 2016] [hphp] [10755:7f41af3ff700:6272:000001] [] SlowTimer [2086ms] at runtime/ext_m
ysql: slow query: SELECT b.bannerid, b.campaignid FROM ox_banners b, ox_campaigns c WHERE b.campaignid =
c.campaignid AND (b.status = 0 OR b.`updated` >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND (c.status = 0 OR c.`updated`
 >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)  AND b.updated >= '2016-11-22 11:03:01';
```

The following logwarn command, looking for `SlowTimer`, finds a matching log, as I expect (output is the entire log line which was added after the last invocation of the command) -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_hiphop_error /mnt/log/hiphop/error_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`.log ".*SlowTimer.*"
```

However, the following command looking for `SlowTimers` also finds a matching log, which I do not expect -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_hiphop_error /mnt/log/hiphop/error_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`.log ".*SlowTimers.*"
```

I tested the regex on https://regex101.com/, and `/.*SlowTimer.*/g` matches whereas `/.*SlowTimers.*/g` does not match anything. I think this is pretty simple regex and works similar across the various flavors.

When the command does not find anything matching (e.g. when there is no new log line after the last invocation), this is the output I get -

```
OK: No log errors found
```

I am expecting the above output when I look for `.*SlowTimers.*`.

Please find [logwarn Manual](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you may need to use the `-p` flag:

> ```
>  -p      Change default match behavior to non-matching.  By default, if a log
>          message doesn't match any of the positive or negative patterns, it is
>          considered a match.  This flag reverses this behavior so that these
>          messages are considered non-matches.
> ```

Also I could be wrong about this but think the regex could be simplified to `SlowTimers` rather than `.*SlowTimers.*`. It isn't specifying start (`^`) and end (`$`) so could appear anywhere in the text.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I need to match the keywords, so I don't see why `-p` should be used to reverse the behavior to consider the keywords as non matches.

Comment: Did you try it? The documentation seems to imply that if a log message doesn't match the regular expression it is still considered a match unless this flag is used.

Comment: You are correct. I think I made some incorrect observation earlier, thinking at the back of my mind that it won't work. I tried with `-p` earlier, and probably, I tried with a non matching keyword first, and while no new line was added to the log file, I tried with a matching keyword and got a "OK: No log errors found" for that reason.

Comment: Could you elaborate this "The documentation seems to imply that if a log message doesn't match the regular expression it is still considered a match unless this flag is used"? Where did you find that in the documentation?

Comment: The `-p` flag [documentation](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage) is: *Change default match behavior to non-matching.  By default, if a log message doesn't match any of the positive or negative patterns, it is considered a match.  This flag reverses this behavior so that these messages are considered non-matches.*

Comment: Please check if you could answer this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716338/modify-regex-match-in-nagios-logwarn-which-matches-against-string-to-not-match