# Modifying regex match in nagios logwarn which matches against string, to not match if followed by another string

Tags: regex, nagios

Considering the following error log, in a log file, which I am using as an input for nagios logwarn command -

```
[19910:7f88e07ff700:559445:000001] [] \nFatal error: File not found: ./postGetAds.php in /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/androidGetAd.php on line 302
```

The following regex works perfect, to detect if a "Fatal" string is present -

```
/^.*Fatal*/g
```

Here is the complete nagios logwarn command where I am using the above regex -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_hiphop_error -p /mnt/log/hiphop/error_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`.log "^.*Fatal*"
```

And here is the output, as was so far desired -

```
Log errors: [Thu Jan 12 07:46:38 2017] [hphp] [19910:7f89543ff700:558024:000001] [] \nFatal error: File not found: ./postGetAd.php in /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/androidGetAd.php on line 302
```

Now, I want to do a modification, to ignore the matching of a log line if there is a string "File not found: " following the "Fatal", as in the above example error log.

The [logwarn documentation](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage) mentions support for a negative checking expression and support for multiple regexpressions in the same command, like this -

```
logwarn -p -m '^myprog: ' '!retrying' 'ERROR'
```

So, I tried the following, which is still not giving the desired result (still matching the file not exists part) -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn_hiphop_error -p /mnt/log/hiphop/error_20170118.log '^.*Fatal*' '!.*File not found\: \.\/postGetAd\.php'
```

In a practical scenario, I would be having multiple file paths whose corresponding "File not found" errors need to be ignored. The best solution could consider that as well.

*Note - the regex here is POSIX flavor.*

Comment: I'm not an expert in logwarn but from the docs it seems that the patterns are ORed so that if the first matches (FATAL) then the second is ignored so using the two together is not helpful as you expect an AND. You could pipe the first command to another command with the negative expression.

Comment: From what I understand POXIS does not support negative expressions.

Comment: @NirLevy regarding your first comment, the description given in the documentation says "Show lines not containing `retrying' but containing `ERROR', as well as any subsequent lines in a multi-line log message, assuming the `myprog: 'prefix marks the start of each new log message." So, it seems it should an AND check. Regarding negative expressions, logwarn supports it, and I have used it successfully.

Comment: You need to specify the negative pattern first. See [the man page](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith you are correct! Please go ahead and add it in an answer and I will choose it as best. By the way, from which line did you conclude that? I found the manual page too difficult to understand.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logwarn` utility accepts a list of positive and negative regular expressions. From [the manual page](https://github.com/archiecobbs/logwarn/wiki/ManPage):

> Each log message is compared against each pattern in the order given.
>   Negative patterns are specified with a ``!'' prefix.  If the log
>   message matches a positive pattern before matching a negative
>   !pattern, or if none of the patterns match, then it's printed to
>   standard output.

So, each line is tested against the patterns **in order**.

- If a positive pattern matches, the line is accepted and no more patterns are tested.
- If a negative pattern matches, the line is rejected and no more patterns are tested.
- If the end of the list is reached with no pattern matches, the line is rejected.

You are looking for lines that include A but do not include B which can be expressed with an AND function: A·!B

Specifying the pattern list as `A !B` will result in the function: A+!B

Whereas specifying the pattern in reverse order `!B A` will result in the function: A·!B

Comment: please see if you can answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906177/unable-to-capture-changes-to-log-file-via-nagios-command-invoked-via-php-exec